# Express is serving files without going through route handlers?

Tags: express

I have the following code:

```
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.resolve('../frontend/dist')));

const server = http.createServer(app);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log('received request');
  res.sendFile(path.resolve('../frontend/dist/index.html'));
});
```

If I comment out the `app.get` handler, index.html is served at `localhost:3000` anyway, apparently due to the second line. The get handler is not actually executing - `received request` is never printed in the console.

But without the second line, it can't serve static assets and JS & CSS fail to load. What am I doing wrong here? Why is the static asset config causing the route to be ignored?

Answer (score 1):

`express.static()` is a generic route handler.  It tries to match incoming requests to specific files at a target location in your file system.  One of the special features it has is that if it gets a request for `/` it will look for `index.html` in the target directory.

You can see the feature described in [the doc](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static) and, in fact, there's an option `{ index: false}` that can turn the feature off if you don't want it to serve `index.html` automatically.